# Handle Event When User Selects A Feature

Tags: arcobjects, c#, events

How do I handle the event when a user selects a feature from a feature layer in ArcObjects?

What I've tried:

```
    public ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_SelectionChangedEventHandler m_ActiveViewEventsSelectionChanged;

    public ArcObjectsController()
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_Event activeViewEvents = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_Event)ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;
        m_ActiveViewEventsSelectionChanged = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnActiveViewEventsSelectionChanged);
        activeViewEvents.SelectionChanged += m_ActiveViewEventsSelectionChanged;
    }

    public void OnActiveViewEventsSelectionChanged()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Event Fired");
    }
```

Comment: Usually you don't wire events in the a constructor. see http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/ViewCodePages/e9d3cad8-0770-466a-a62d-6cd9d059c464Form1.cs.htm

Comment: That shouldn't be causing me not to be able to handle the event, it's still wired up correctly.

Comment: If you wire it a Document's focused map, and then the focused map changes, then your handler won't get called. Likewise if the app opens a new or existing document, you'll need to re-wire your listener.  Did you try it in a simple form, as shown in the example?

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.. I will try that and get back.

Comment: I've found no problems wiring in the constructor for IEditEvents etc; if you want to offset your load wire them in your OnActivate and unwire in OnDeactivate (Important!). Did you let the IDE create the function for you? I had problems when I copy/pasted an event function and the IDE ignored it and wanted to create an Event2 function. Updated snippet (10.1 to 10.3) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000051000000

Comment: Are you sure that the selection was made in the FocusMap and not in one of the possible other maps? IMaps maps = ArcMap.Document.Maps;